# Make button a link to PDF file with Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to link a pdf to a button using the bootstrap framework in Rails. For example the button would say download now and link to the PDF. I'm not concerned on how the PDF opens, just that it links to it.

In the Bootstrap documentation it says to use only the `<a>` tag and it doesn't mention anything about the `<%= link_to %>` tag. This is what's listed in the Bootstrap doc's `<a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">Download Now</a>`, where "Download Now" is the text show on the button.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it works just as normal. replace # in href="#" by your pdf doc path.

Comment: You just make a link like this : `<%= link_to download_path, :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger" do %>Download Now<% end %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify class as one of the arguments of `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "Download Now", '/path/to/file/or/path_method', :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to '/path/to/file/or/path_method', :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger" do %>
  Download Now
<% end %>
```

[Rails Framework Documentation for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

Comment: When I did this, I get `No route matches [GET] "/images/Products.pdf"`. I guess I need to define a route for the file, but I'm not sure of the exact syntax to use to do that. As you can tell the file is called Products.pdf and I have it in my /assets/images/ foler

Comment: Try asset_path('images/Products.pdf') instead of straight up path

Comment: I figured it out. I put the file in the file in the Public folder and this code `<%= link_to asset_path("Products.pdf"), :class => "btn btn-large btn-danger" do %>  Download Now <% end %>', thanks for the help